# How do German speakers translate sounds that animals make?

Tags: translation, onomatopoeia

I have always been interested in the ways that animal sounds are "translated" in foreign languages. Presumably, the sounds are the same to our ears.

In English:

- Dog: woof
- Cat: meow
- Cow: moo
- Duck: quack
- Frog: ribbit

How are these translated by German ears?

Comment: Reminds me of a great French lesson: "What does *quoique* mean?" - "That's the sound frogs make in France." Might only work with a German audience, though ;)

Comment: Ich meine die Prämisse ist falsch. Viele Tiere haben eine große Varianz an Lauten, die sie ausstoßen, so dass die Laute, die einer Verschriftlichung zu Grunde liegen, viel eher voneinander abweichen, als dass sie zufällig identisch sind.

Comment: Eine Kuh macht Muh. Viele Kühe machen Mühe.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

These are words which are commonly used in German:

- dog: *wau wau* (verb: bellen)
- cat: *miau* (verb: miauen)
- cow: *muh* (verb: muhen)
- duck: *quak* (verb: quaken)
- frog: *quak* (verb: quaken)

Other animals:

- rooster: *kikeriki* (verb: krähen)
- donkey: *i-ah*
- sheep: *mäh* or *bäh* (verb: blöken)
- bird: *piep piep* (verb: zwitschern)
- horse: - (verb: wiehern)
- owl: *hu hu*

Comment: @Gigili: Correct, though written *summ summ* in German. @splattne: Maybe the variants *wuff* for dogs and *maunz* for cats? At least I've heard them as much as the other ones.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Just saw that in Takkat's answer!

Answer (score 7):

Animal sounds are made up to sound similar when spoken ([Onomatopoeia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia)), using doubling of the sound in some times. Your examples will translate as follows:

- Dog: woof = *Wauwau*
- Cat: meow = *Miau*
- Cow: moo = *Muh*
- Duck: quack = *Qua[c]k*
- Frog: ribbit = *Qua[c]k*

Here are some more examples:

- Bird: = *Piep[piep]*
- Bee: = *Summ[summ]*
- Donkey: = *Ia[ia]*
- Goat: = *Meh*
- Sheep: = *Mäh*

Answer (score 4):

[English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_sounds) has some nice links to this

- [A multilingual list](http://www.eleceng.adelaide.edu.au/Personal/dabbott/animal.html)
- [People from several countries interpreting the sounds](http://www.bzzzpeek.com/)
- [A kind of quiz](http://www.lexiophiles.com/english/old-macdonald-had-a-farm)
- [German Wikipedia explains some of them](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tierlautbezeichnungen)